# Braille codifier

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to make a braille codifier-decodifier in Java, but i'm having trouble when choosing the method (user chooses what does he want to do, codifie or de-codifie and which file does he want to cod./de-cod). This is the program so far (to choose and open the file):

```
public static void main (String []args) throws Exception {  
    System.out.println("Escriba 'c' para codificar o 'd' para decodificar: ");  
    char e=(char) System.in.read();  
        switch (e){  
            case 'd':  
                System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del fichero a decodificar sin    <.txt>. Por defecto, <Entrada>: ");  
                break;  
            case 'c':  
                System.out.println("Introduzca nombre del fichero a codificar sin <.txt>. Por defecto, <Entrada>: ");  
                break;  
        }
        }
    }
```

1st println translated: `Enter c to codify or d to de-codify`

2nd-3rd println translated: `Enter file's name to de-codify/codify without ".txt". By default, 'entrada'`

I don't know how to make it that the program will keep running, wait for user to enter the file's name (or just press "enter" and open "entrada" file by default), open it, send it to another class to codify/de-codify it and then write it back into the file, and finish the program.

I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.2.1

Sorry, for my bad grammar, I tried to make my best. If there was something that you don't understand, reply and I'll explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Scanner (java.util.Scanner) when you need to get input from the user. The code would look something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Creates a scanner that reads the System.in stream
String filepath = scanner.nextLine(); // Reads until it reaches a line break and returns what was read.
```

Comment: Error "non-static method nextLine() cannot be referenced from a static context". Also, where would I place that, after the println in switch or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry about that I capitalized Scanner by accident. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, tried it, but program stops before i could enter file's name. Also, where will the program store file's name? And, after introducing file's name (and 'd' or 'c'), how i open it, send it to the de-cod. or cod., and write the result in another file? (by default, 'salida).